# Distriqt PushNotification event NOTIFICATION_SELECTED won't fire (VERSION = 6)

Tags: push-notification, air, google-cloud-messaging, ane, distriqt

Distriqt PushNotification version 6.0.029
I use PushNotificationsHelper in the example folder, there are few issues as below:

1. For initialize PushNotifications.isSupported return true, but once I call register and it return false again. I ending up commented //PushNotifications.isSupported for each of the call function to make sure it works. Ok, it works and I received registration token.
2. I use GCM playload, notification field just try to display very simple notification title and body. Ok, I received notification popup in background but when I select the notification, the PushNotificationEvent.NOTIFICATION_SELECTED event won't firing, this the critical issue in my project.
3. When I use Distriqt playload, data field. I received notification silently when in background, nothing show up (Why?). And I received data dispatched from event PushNotificationEvent.NOTIFICATION this fine. FYI, I enabled service.enableNotificationsWhenActive = true

   - The GCM playload format from http://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.PushNotifications#sending

Please read my project setup for the ane extensions included:

1. com.distriqt.PushNotifications
2. com.distriqt.Core
3. com.distriqt.playservices.GCM
4. com.distriqt.AndroidSupport
5. com.distriqt.playservices.Base

Device tested:

1. Mi Note (Android version 6.0.1)
2. Samsung Galaxy S3 (Android version 4.1.2)

Can anyone please advice where do i make mistake or it's the native extension issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ask your question in the github issue tracker (https://github.com/distriqt/ANE-PushNotifications/issues) we'll help you through the issues you are having.

Most likely your issue is that your `data` payload doesn't contain the minimum fields for the notification display, i.e. `title` and `alert`.

Also, make sure you have the latest version of the support ANEs (Core, AndroidSupport and play services). This can cause issues.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for your answer. The github link above page not found. Anyway, I have used the latest version of the ANEs from https://github.com/distriqt. When I select the notification from background, why the PushNotificationEvent.NOTIFICATION_SELECTED won't fire? Please advise. Thanks

Comment: You only have access to that repository if you are a subscribed customer. It's part of our support and updates subscription. How are you downloading the ANEs if not from that repository?

Comment: Ok. Will move the question to distriqt github. Thanks